# Проект VSC++ 2008 под linux

Tags: linux, visual-c++

Всем привет. Есть проект VisualStudio 2008, его надо собрать на linux-сервере. При сборке возникают ошибки, первая из которых:

```
./src/StdAfx.h: error: ManagementNode.h: No such file or directory
```

Дело в том, что ManagementNode.h находится в папке src.gen, которая при компиляции не генерируется, чтоли. Доступ к linux-серверу по ssh. Подскажите, в какую сторону копать, чтобы собралось, а то линуксоед из меня тот еще? Под Windows проект собирается. Что может быть нужно проекту для создания src.gen? Нужны какие-то особые условия?

И еще вопрос: так ли важно для сборки проекта, какие слэши в файлах *.sln, *.vcproj и Makefile? А то в Makefile в путях стоит "/", а в *.sln, *.vcproj и прямой слэш, и обратный.

---

Теперь проблемы с регистрацией dll: `SettingsBuilder.dll can't be registered (registration procedure failed) make: *** Error 1` . Как узнать какие файлы нужны dll для регистрации?

Comment: **проект VisualStudio 2008, его надо собрать на linux-сервере** - страння идея... А почему нельзя воспользоваться gcc + make ?

Comment: Проект создан в VisualStudio 2008 и под Windows в ней же и собирается. На Linux он и собирается через g++ и make. вот только не собирается. Почему-то не находит хедеры, хотя пути к ним прописаны, и сами файлы есть.

Comment: Как именно прописаны хедеры? Вы используете ключ -I в котором задаёте директорию с хедерами? Может быть Вы просто спутали ключи -I и -l, которые визуально практически не различимы ?

Comment: Используются -I../../../../../include/. В общем хедеры с горем пополам видно. Но папки src.gen нет. Она генерируется только при сборке студией?

Comment: **Она генерируется только при сборке студией?** - про студию я ничего не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

собрать *это* нельзя, можно только портировать. но это отдельная и весьма трудоемкая для начинающего задача, один из вариантов:

- пишем правильный makefile
- портируем libc API
- портируем windows specific API
- портируем различия в реализации c++ стандарта
- заменяем оставшиеся библиотеки близкими по функционалу (или кроссплатформенными)

проще запустить собраный вендой exe под wine. нормальные приложения пишут **думая  заранее** о его возможности кросс-компиляции под win/mac/linux

Comment: Это уже сделано, я ковыряю далеко не свой локальный проект. Вот только собрать не получается. Как определить какой из пунктов хромает? Ошибка указана в первом посте.

Comment: Теперь жалуется на `Xalan: error while loading shared libraries: libxalan`. Как узнать по каким путям она ищется?